# Dynamic div with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dynamic

What would be the best way to replace the contents of a div using jQuery? Here is an example of my application:

```
<div id="size">
    <p>Waiting for item</p>
</div>
```

Once the item is selected, size is either size-sml (which is a jquery buttonset) or size-l depending on the item type.

```
<div id="size-sml" style="display: none">
    <input id="s_r1" name="radio" type="radio"><label for="s_r1">Small</label>
    <input id="s_r2" name="radio" type="radio"><label for="s_r2">Medium</label>
    <input id="s_r3" name="radio" type="radio"><label for="s_r3">Large</label>
</div>
```

or

```
<div id="size-l" style="display: none">
    <label for="liters">Volume in liters: </label>
    <input id="liters">
</div>
```

I was using .html() to change the div, but this resulted in an error "cannot call methods on button prior to initialization, attempted to call method 'widget'" whenever I pressed one of the small medium large buttons. Regular text input works fine.

JavaScript:

```
var size = $( "#size" );
var types = $( "#types" ); //jQuery buttonset
types.click( function() {
    sizeType = $( "#types :radio:checked" ).attr( "st" );
    if ( sizeType == "G" ) {
        size.html( $( "#size-sml" ).html() );
        size.buttonset();
    } else if ( sizeType == "L" ) {
        size.html( $( "#size-l" ).html() );
    }
});
```

Comment: Please include your javascript as that's most likely where the issue is.

Comment: @couzzi There. #types is a buttonset similar to the sml buttonset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you were doing wrong, or why you were getting that error, because you didn't provide the markup for `#types`, or the javascript that initialized it. I rebuilt those pieces from what was provided, and it appears to be working for me. Some small changes to your code:

#### Plunk : http://plnkr.co/edit/7dvzrb0Mzpg80bApmTmi?p=preview

```
$(function(){
  $("#types").buttonset();
  $("#types :radio").click(function(e) {
      var sizeType = $(this).attr( "st" );
      if ( sizeType == "G" ) {
      $("#size").html( $( "#size-sml" ).html() )
                .buttonset();
      } else if ( sizeType == "L" ) {
          ("#size").html( $( "#size-l" ).html() );
      }
    });
});
```

I believe the root of your problem is this `sizeType = $( "#types :radio:checked" ).attr( "st" );` which does **not** return a single result. So, instead of a click event on the parent, I put it on the children who are `:radio`.

Comment: That tool is amazing! Had I known about it before, I would have included a link in the question ^^

I created a demo using the fix that you provided and it's working flawlessly ([link](http://plnkr.co/edit/7rlzMh)). The issue before was that clicking Small, Medium, or Large resulted in that strange error.

Comment: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co) or [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) are really helpful for asking/answering questions on SO. Glad I could help.

Comment: Also, my last question: is this the best way to do this?

Comment: There are many ways to skin a cat; without knowing the ins-and-outs of what you're building, it's hard to say. I'd never used `jQuery UI` prior to researching your question, if that's what you mean. If you run into any more issues, open another question and we'll take it from there. Good luck.